# How do I incorporate Ito's lemma into the solution for a finite-horizon stochastic cake-eating problem?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming

I'm interested in finite-horizon, continuous-time cake-eating problems in which the agent has a time-horizon $W$ over which to eat the cake, and then chooses an optimal consumption path $\{h_t\}_0^W$, subject to stochastic utility shocks.

In particular, my setting has a Brownian process $a_t \sim G(a)$ with $\mathbb{E}[a] = 1$, and the instantaneous utility from eating $h_t$ cake is $a_tv(h_t)$.

The agent discounts the future at a rate $\rho$, so the formulation of the optimization problem is:

$$
\max_{\lbrace h_t\rbrace_0^W} \mathbb{E}_0 \left[ \int_0^W e^{-\rho t} \times a_t v(h_t(S_t,a_t)) dt \right]
$$

where $h_t(S_t,a_t)$ is cake consumption as a function of the amount of cake let $S_t$ and the utility shock $a_t$.

I'm familiar with discrete-time optimization using Bellman equations, and have been reading about solutions to continuous-time optimization via the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation. However, I haven't found a single full solution method for the case with a finite horizon *and* stochastic utility.

So far, my approach has been to write down the HJB equation which looks like:

$$
\rho \mathcal{V}(S,a,t) = \max_h a v(h) + \mathbb{E} \, \mathcal{V}^\prime(S,a,t) \dot{S}(h)
$$

where $S$ is the amount of cake left and the following transition equations and boundary conditions hold:

$$
\dot{S_t} = -h_t(S,a_t) \quad S_W = 0 \quad S_0 = T
$$

But I don't know if this equation & set of conditions fully characterizes the solution. In particular, based on my reading of Ito's lemma, I'm not sure if I need to add a second condition on the solution path which takes Ito into account.

Since I'm working with a general form of utility $v$, I don't need to find a closed-form solution (I'll eventually take a discrete approximation and solve the associated Bellman equation via value function iteration), but I'd like to make sure that I'm writing down the 'correct' solution form to the continuous-time equation.

**Addendum**: Is the solution to the problem any different if $W$ is a choice variable (i.e. if the agent chooses the finite horizon over which to eat the cake), or can I treat that optimization step separately from the HJB of the optimal path choice?